# How to force re-render entire component when passed-in prop changed in react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

Following is a simplified version of my code.

- I have a dropdown that I can select empty, car, ship.
- When dropdown value is changed, in my `Test` component, I have a useEffect to monitor the pass-in value `testValue`.
- If the pass-in value `testValue` changed, I want to re-render the entire `Test` component with `testValue` has the latest changed value.

Currently, not sure how to achieve it?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Test({ testValue }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("force ENTIRE Test component re-render");
  }, [testValue]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>other components</div>
      <div>test me: {testValue}</div>
      <div>other components</div>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [optionState, setOptionState] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        value={optionState}
        onChange={e => setOptionState(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="">please select</option>
        <option value="car">car</option>
        <option value="ship">ship</option>
      </select>
      <Test testValue={optionState} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @ritaj, sorry, I don't understand. My understanding is that testValue is changed, but 2 other components never re-render itself

Comment: React is meant not to draw that's not changed, that's the whole point of the DOM differ.  so of course it won't re-render the other 2.. Why do you want it too?

Comment: @Keith, doing something like this? https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/force-refreshing-a-react-child-component-the-easy-way-6cdbb9e6d99c/

Comment: Could you explain what your trying to do, because even in that link the reasons for forcing a refresh didn't add up..  The reasons he gave for forcing one were invalid.